# Determine whether has NotificationListener needed permission. Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

I have a service:

```
public class NotificationCatcher extends NotificationListenerService
```

which has declared permission in the manifest like:

```
<service
        android:name=".tasks.NotificationCatcher"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

How can I determine whether is `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`? When I can't use `checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission)` because I don't have `Context`.
When I use `Context` from `MainActivity` I get exception and my Android app crashes.

What I want to achieve:
`MainActivity` determines whether has `NotificationCatcher` `android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` and then perform action.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Context in service

Call to **getApplicationContext()** function.

Comment: I've already tried and this is the result
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I was also surprised that the following didn't work

```
    val granted = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE)
```

Here's the solution (tested on Android 11)

```
    val granted = android.provider.Settings.Secure
            .getString(contentResolver, "enabled_notification_listeners")
            .contains(applicationContext.packageName)
```